# How to automatically cite your own publications in a resume?

Tags: biblatex, cv, biblatex-publist

Is there a biblatex style (or another mean to generate this automatically) designed to autocite (citing your own work)? It could be useful in a resume or for exporting to your website a list of publications.

Here is a example of what I want:

In my (zotero) library, I have my works. If I cite these papers, I will obtain something like:

> John Doe, *Electric equilibrium*, Journal of quantum mechanic, 2043 (2), 143-157

*But*, when you create a list of publications, you may want (and I do) to remove author which is irrelevant in this context and replace it by a dot (list item). Like this:

> - *Electric equilibrium*, Journal of quantum mechanic, 2043 (2), 143-157

And if you have multi-authors papers, you may want to replace

> John Doe and foo bar , *Electric equilibrium*, Journal of quantum mechanic, 2043 (2), 143-157

by (note the "with"):

> - *Electric equilibrium* (with foo bar), Journal of quantum mechanic, 2043 (2), 143-157

I would like to save me the pain to do this by hand.

Comment: Here it is an example http://texblog.org/2012/04/25/writing-a-cv-in-latex/ that I think it illustrates that it doesn't worth it to use bibtex for a CV, because you need a lot of customization (like yours) for usually a small number of entries (do you have hundreds of articles published? congrats if so.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

run `texdoc biblatex-publist` from the command line or visit http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-publist It is a special style for a publication  list in a cv. A complete example can be found at `$TEXMF/doc/latex/latex-referenz/10-03-22.ltx` which should be available in your current TeX distribution or available on CTAN.